# How can place 7 images across 2 rows in a 'figure'?

Tags: graphics, floats, subfig

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \subfloat[Distribution of herring in 2018]{
    \begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
       0.2\textwidth}
      % \centering
       \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{hp2018.png}
    \end{minipage}}
 \hfill     
  \subfloat[Distribution of herring in 2019]{
    \begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
       0.2\textwidth}
     %  \centering
       \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{hp2019.png}
    \end{minipage}}
 \hfill 
  \subfloat[Distribution of herring in 2020]{
    \begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
       0.2\textwidth}
    %   \centering
       \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{hp2020.png}
    \end{minipage}}
 \hfill
\subfloat[Distribution of herring in 2021]{
    \begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
       0.2\textwidth}
      % \centering
       \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{hp2021.png}
    \end{minipage}}
\hfill  
  \subfloat[Distribution of mackere in 2016]{
    \begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
       0.2\textwidth}
      % \centering
       \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{mp2018.png}
    \end{minipage}}
 \hfill 
  \subfloat[Distribution of mackere in 2019]{
    \begin{minipage}[c][1\width]{
       0.2\textwidth}
    %   \centering
       \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{mp2019.png}
    \end{minipage}}
 \hfill
\subfloat[Distribution of mackere in 2020]{
    \begin{minipage}[][1\width]{
       0.2\textwidth}
     %  \centering
       \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{mp2020.png}
    \end{minipage}}
\caption{Predicter distribution of herring and mackere in 2018-2021}\label{18-21}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The figures in the second row are not centered. How to make them in one place or make them just below the figures in the first row?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

I would use `subfigure` environment defined in the `subcaption` package, remove `minipage`s and `subfloat`s:

**Edit:**
for image width is now considered @Mico suggestion in his comment. With `\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}` and appropriate selected width of `subfigure`s the figure will stay inside text width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}   
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.22\textwidth}
\includegraphics{hp2018.png}
\caption{Distribution of herring in 2018}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.22\textwidth}
\includegraphics{hp2019.png}
\caption{Distribution of herring in 2019}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.22\textwidth}
\includegraphics{hp2020.png}
\caption{Distribution of herring in 2020}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.22\textwidth}
\includegraphics{hp2021.png}
\caption{Distribution of herring in 2021}
    \end{subfigure}

\medskip
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.22\textwidth}
\includegraphics{mp2018.png}
\caption{Distribution of mackere in 2016}
    \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.22\textwidth}
\includegraphics{mp2019.png}
\caption{Distribution of mackere in 2019}
    \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.22\textwidth}
\includegraphics{mp2020.png}
\caption{Distribution of mackere in 2020}
    \end{subfigure}

\caption{Predicter distribution of herring and mackere in 2018-2021}\label{18-21}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. To assure that the objects fit inside the width of the text block, though, do change `\setkeys{Gin}{width=3cm,height=3cm}` to `\setkeys{Gin}{width=\textwidth}`, and do omit `[width=3cm,height=3cm]` in the seventh and final `\includegraphics` instruction.

Comment: @Mico, you are (as usual) right.I just left OP setting .. I will consider your suggestion asap.

Comment: @Mico, done. Before this was not visible on image ....

Answer (score 2):

If you want the subfigures in the second row to be aligned below those in the first row, don't use `\hfill` as the separator. If you assign relative widths of, say, `0.22\textwidth` to the subfigures, that leaves `0.04\texwidth` for each of the three instances of whitespace in the first row; hence, replace `\hfill` with `hspace*{0.04\textwidth}` and you're mostly done. (`4*0.22+3*0.04=1`.)

Do leave a blank line after the first four subfigures, though, to force LaTeX to insert an explicit linebreak. I further suggest that you not state fixed widths and heights for the images in the argument of `\includegraphics`. Instead, use *relative dimensions* such as `\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \subfloat[Distribution of herring in 2018]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{hp2018}
    \end{minipage}}
  \hspace*{0.04\textwidth}% 
  \subfloat[Distribution of herring in 2019]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{hp2019}
    \end{minipage}}
  \hspace*{0.04\textwidth}%
  \subfloat[Distribution of herring in 2020]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{hp2020}
    \end{minipage}}
  \hspace*{0.04\textwidth}%
\subfloat[Distribution of herring in 2021]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{hp2021}
    \end{minipage}}
% Insert a blank line to force a line break:

  \subfloat[Distribution of mackerel in 2016]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mp2018}
    \end{minipage}}
  \hspace*{0.04\textwidth}%
  \subfloat[Distribution of mackerel in 2019]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mp2019}
    \end{minipage}}
  \hspace*{0.04\textwidth}%
  \subfloat[Distribution of mackerel in 2020]{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.22\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mp2020}
    \end{minipage}}

\caption{Predictor distribution of herring and mackerel in 2018--2021}\label{18-21}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```